# Are there alternatives to SIP Trunking?

Tags: protocols, sip, voip, network-protocols, sip-server

I'm not sure if this is a stackoverflow question but,

To my understanding SIP Trunking is a VOIP protocol that 
allows a person to call through a phoneline and than some datacenter will convert that into an internet call.

My question is, is it the only protocol? Are there other protocols that can be used for VOIP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists a technology known as PRI. Both PRI (Primary rate interface)and SIP(Session Initiating Protocol) are used connect  your business to Public PSTN networks. 
 PRI and SIP both needs a physical connection to PSTN network. The problem is more conventional in such way that it uses Circuit switched model and only support Voice messages.
 Sip uses existing data channel and uses packet switched model to communication, we can send voice and sometimes FAX messages through SIP.
  In business point of view, SIP is more scalable and profitable compared to PRI service(Even though a PRI offers more Quality Voice service). 
Traditionally fixed line VS SIP configuration

[image]

[image]

Comment: PRI is an ISDN protocol and not a VoIP protocol.  The two are not really comparable, specifically since you cannot use PRI or BRI over a TCP network, PRI is hardware routed while SIP uses TCP routing, and PRI requires a specific hardware connection to the PSTN, while SIP will work over ANY Internet / TCP link (including [345]G, WiFi, etc...)